# ngx-translate not working on production after upgrade to Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error, ngx-translate, angular11

I recently upgraded to angular 11 and for some reason my translations stopped working in production mode. After the upgrade when I open my app in debug, all of my translations are empty  but I do have some errors. Everything works fine in dev but in production I get a couple errors which are:

```
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29367)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:62513)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29367)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:62531)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29380)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:62555)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29380)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:62579)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29380)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:62603)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29380)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:62629)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:40061 In home component - onInit merchant:
main.js:formatted:29600 each event url :/serverOrder
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29380)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:40348)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29380)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:62747)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
Tt @ main.js:formatted:17916
main.js:formatted:7596 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
main.js:formatted:7640 [WDS] Warnings while compiling.
warnings @ main.js:formatted:7640
2main.js:formatted:7646 Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename 3rdpartylicenses.txt
warnings @ main.js:formatted:7646
main.js:formatted:17916 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
    at t.get (main.js:formatted:29380)
    at t.updateValue (main.js:formatted:29480)
    at t.transform (main.js:formatted:29502)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:52939)
    at Object.updateRenderer (main.js:formatted:22658)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21728)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
    at jr (main.js:formatted:22075)
    at Pr (main.js:formatted:21724)
    at Vr (main.js:formatted:22090)
```

my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.0.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/w3c-web-usb": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.4",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.4.3",
    "angular-cc-library": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "got": "^11.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.0.2",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.4",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng-thermal-print": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "pusher": "^2.2.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
    "readable-stream": "^3.6.0",
    "remote-pay-cloud": "3.1.0",
    "remote-pay-cloud-api": "^4.0.3",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "resize-base64": "^1.0.12",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.135",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.66",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.13",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should try upgrading ngx-translate as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade ur ngx-translate package version from v8 to v13 which supports angular 10+

"@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",

Check: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core

Comment: Tried that before but it didnt work, this time I upgraded it, deleted my node modules and hit npm install and that fixed it for me.